# AsyncHTTPTestCase Tornado 599

Tags: tornado

I'm trying to use the AsyncHTTPTestCase example, but I keep getting a 599 error.

I have tried the same example below, but without the coroutine decorators and just using self.fetch, but I still get the same error.

### app.py

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen


class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")
        self.finish()


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", Handler)
    ])
```

### test_app.py

```
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase, gen_test
from app import make_app


class TestApp(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        make_app()

    @gen_test(timeout=100)
    def test_handler(self):
        response = yield self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url("/"))
        assert response == "Hello, world"
```

Testing command

```
pytest test_app.py
```

### Environment

- Tornado=5.0.2
- Python=3.6.5

### Error

`tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 599: Stream closed`

Any insight or help as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the test_app.py file.

### test_app.py

```
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase, gen_test
from app import make_app


class TestApp(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        return make_app()

    @gen_test(timeout=100)
    def test_handler(self):
        response = yield self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url("/"))
        assert response.body == b"Hello, world"
```

Note the `return` in the `get_app` function.

I have also edited the assert to have a test that passes.